# Sql Query to pull only one record from table 'Academic' based on condition

Tags: select

I have a table like below

id | status | EffDate     |
1  | A      | 12-Dec-2020 |
1  | T      | 17-Dec-2022 |

I need to pull the data from the above table based on a condition as below:

1. Get the record if the status is in ('A','W'),
2. get the record with status = 'T' if the 1st condition fails.
   At a time I need only one record inthe output.

I'm trying with Case when then else end but I'm doing something wrong.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT id, status, EffDate
FROM your_table
WHERE 
  status IN ('A', 'W') 
  OR (
    status = 'T' 
    AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 
      FROM your_table 
      WHERE status IN ('A', 'W') 
      AND id = your_table.id
    )
  )
LIMIT 1;
```

Explanation:

- The WHERE clause filters the records based on the given conditions.
- The IN operator is used to check if the status is either 'A' or 'W'.
- The OR operator is used to retrieve the record with status = 'T' if the first condition fails.
- The NOT EXISTS subquery is used to check if there is no record with status = 'A' or 'W' for the same id.
- The LIMIT clause is used to retrieve only one record from the result set.